# When cursor data not found how to insert the date

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a cursor C_RegstCursor and when WHEN C_RegstCursor %notfound then i want to insert psome record to the table.

```
 FETCH C_RegstCursor INTO
       f--fetc values to variable                 
     v_reg_comment;

 WHEN C_RegstCursor %notfound then
```

insert data to the table..and a set of statements to insert to multiple tables

if i try to run the cursor it gives an error
Symbol "WHEN" encountered when one of the following was expected:

( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod NULL
pragma raise return select update whil

How do i write when in case of notfound and should i exit after the insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you wanted, one option is to use a local variable which counts number of rows returned by cursor. If there were no rows, do the insert.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From dept order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Procedure; obviously, there's no `deptno = 99` so cursor won't return anything.

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c1 is select deptno, dname, loc
  3      from dept
  4      where deptno = 99;
  5    c1r c1%rowtype;
  6    l_cnt number := 0;
  7  begin
  8    open c1;
  9    loop
 10      fetch c1 into c1r;
 11      exit when c1%notfound;
 12      l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
 13
 14      -- do something within the loop, if there are any rows returned by cursor
 15    end loop;
 16    close c1;
 17
 18    if l_cnt = 0 then
 19       -- cursor didn't return anything
 20       insert into dept (deptno, dname, loc)
 21         values (99, 'Test', 'Test');
 22    end if;
 23  end;
 24  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from dept order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        99 Test           Test             --> newly added row

SQL>
```